# Accessory Type в ячейке

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

В секции есть несколько ячеек, так вот надо чтобы при выборе какой-либо ячейки - была галочка только у неё, а у остальных ячеек из этой секции убиралась. Так вот я пишу так:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for (int i=0;i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:indexPath.section];
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Но если у меня например секция из 50 ячеек, то когда я выбрал ячейку вначале, то при выборе ячейки в конце - галочка у первой не убирается, то есть получается уже 2 галочки в секции.

Comment: @97mik, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @AlessandroDP Дело в том, что я не знаю какой ответ более правильный (подходящий), поэтому я начал изучать Obj C с нуля, а когда дойду до UITableView, тогда и смогу сделать вывод какой ответ мне более подходит.

Answer (score 1):

Запоминаешь indexPath выбранной ячейки, а в

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

проверяй, установлена ли галка на ячейке, аля:

```
if (indexPath.row == self.idx)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

[[[[@Anastasia](/users/10714/anastasia)](/users/10714/anastasia)](/users/10714/anastasia)](/users/10714/anastasia), вы все равно вводите в заблуждение. Зачем перезагружать таблицу без надобности?? Изначально получается неверный подход. (Здесь пишу коммент, так как не могу к вашему добавить, ниже также не добавляется и редактировать могу только ответ:) - администрация, что с добавлением комментариев?)

[[[[@Anastasia](/users/10714/anastasia)](/users/10714/anastasia)](/users/10714/anastasia)](/users/10714/anastasia), соглашусь, что ваш вариант работает :), однако повторюсь: НЕправильно перезагружать таблицу, если можно обойтись и без этого, а уж тем более в таком простом случае. А если бы у вас оч много данных было? Это неверный подход и тем самым вы направляете «Падована» не в ту степь, имхо. Как то так :)

Comment: Так таблица уже создана статистически и надо расставлять галки в процессе работы приложения.

Comment: Поставьте брейкпоинт в методе cellForRowAtIndexPath да посмотрите, сколько раз он вызовется)). Матчасть..., срочно...

Comment: Столько же раз сколько и ячеек наверное.

Comment: Ну так не работает или что??)) Пишите конкретно - помогло/нет. В чем еще проблема?

Comment: cell не находит.

Comment: Ну так надо же ее запомнить в методе (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPa и все.

Comment: Вот почему просто не написать всё за один раз, полностью, с объяснением? Вместо этого я вынужден по сто раз дёргать свой код чтобы в итоге получить не рабочее приложение.

Comment: А вот почему не поучить МАТЧАСТЬ или элементарно загуглить, чтоб не задавать такие глупейшие/простейшие вопросы, да еще и возмущаться??? На stackoverflow уже давно заминусовали бы такой вопрос, да даже задать не дали бы!! Это здесь лояльно еще относятся.

@Anastasia, и зачем это перезагружать таблицу?? Не вводите в заблуждение!

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property NSIndexPath *checkedPath;
@end

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    // create cell
    // ...
    if ([self.checkedPath isEqual:indexPath])
    {
        outCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        outCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.checkedPath = indexPath;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: @AlessandroDP Я разобралась, как вы делаете в вашем примере. Наверное, так даже лучше, чем перегружать таблицу. Пусть мой ответ будет отдельно - просто другой подход, и он тоже работает. Я уберу ссылку на ваш ответ из ответа и свой комментарий.